Unable to turn on secure boot
The secure boot on my ThinkPad T14 Gen4 is turned off. So, I tryed to turn it on by following the instructions on the Lenovo page.
But then, after saving and exiting, the following window pops up:

I searched online, but just found videos explaining how to solve the "Secure Boot Violation: invalid signature detected" by disabling the secure boot! I want to enable it.
How can I fix the Secure Boot Violation and enable the secure boot?

That's what happens when I exit.
I boot from the internal hard drive.
Anyway, the first link in the answer I accepted solved my problem.

The question doesn't mention which operating system is on the ThinkPad.
While I don't have a ThinkPad to verify a solution, a search for that error message found some suggestions:

In "Secure boot violation - invalid signature detected" Ubuntu 24.04 LTS which is for a Thinkpad Z13 Gen 2:

The solution was to enable "third-party" UEFI certificates in BIOS. After that, I can install Ubuntu and even use Secure Boot.


In [KB8389] Enable 3rd party certificates in Secure Boot for ESET Endpoint Encryption and ESET Full Disk Encryption which mentions a solution for a ThinkPad T14 the solution is:


Open ThinkPad Secure Boot Configuration.
Click Security. Click the toggle next to Allow Microsoft 3rd Party UEFI CA.




